# How to pass a styled component instead of string message to formik's thanks response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, formik

My formik contact form returns a "thanks" string under the form after it is successfully submitted, and I want it to return a styled component instead so it can be styled.

This successfully returns string "thanks" message, though it is unstyled:

```
const ContactForm = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()

    const [serverState, setServerState] = useState()
    const handleServerResponse = (ok, msg) => {
        setServerState({ ok, msg })
    }

    const handleOnSubmit = (values, actions) => {
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://formspree.io/user-id",
            data: values
        })
            .then(response => {
                actions.setSubmitting(false)
                actions.resetForm()
                handleServerResponse(true, "Thanks!") //returns unstyled string at the bottom of the page
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
                handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
            })
    }
```

This returns nothing at all:

```
const ContactForm = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()

    const [serverState, setServerState] = useState()
    const handleServerResponse = (ok, msg) => {
        setServerState({ ok, msg })
    }

    const handleOnSubmit = (values, actions) => {
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://formspree.io/user-id",
            data: values
        })
            .then(response => {
                actions.setSubmitting(false)
                actions.resetForm()
                handleServerResponse(true, () => { 
                    return (
                        <Thanks>Thanks!</Thanks>  // styled component I'd like to return
                    )
                }
              )
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
                handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
            })
    }
```

How can I successfully reference my own component here? here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-meadow-pc8xm?file=/src/App.js) I put together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
const ContactForm = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()

    const [serverState, setServerState] = useState()
    const handleServerResponse = (ok, msg) => {
        setServerState({ ok, msg })
    }

    const handleOnSubmit = (values, actions) => {
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://formspree.io/user-id",
            data: values
        })
            .then(response => {
                actions.setSubmitting(false)
                actions.resetForm()
                handleServerResponse(true, "Thanks!") //returns unstyled string at the bottom of the page
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
                handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
            })
    }

    if (serverState && serverState.ok && serverState.msg) return <Thanks>{ serverState.msg }</Thanks>;
```

If you need to show the form or whatever as well, then include the conditional within your existing return :).

e.g.

```
  return (
     <Fragment>
         <form>
             ...
         </form>
         { serverState && serverState.ok && serverState.msg && (
              <Thanks>{ serverState.msg }</Thanks>
         )}
     </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: I had tried this before but I guess I needed to put in inside the return.. whoops. Thanks!! This works :)

Comment: Awesome! No problem! :)